# Pandas: DataFrame Error - 2 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to initializes a dataframe and set its column and index as shown below but I face some issues while do like this:

```
pd1 = pd.DataFrame(Matrix, columns=da, index=cl)
```

From above Matrix define as:

```
Matrix = [[[0], [0], [0]],
          [[0], [0], [0]]]
```

and da as:

```
da = ['A','B']
```

and cl as:

```
cl = ['X','Y','Z']
```

following error is occur while executing this line:

```
# caller's responsibility to check for this..
raise AssertionError('%d columns passed, passed data had %s '
                     'columns' % (len(columns), len(content)))
# provide soft conversion of object dtypes

AssertionError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns
```

how to resolve this problem in python dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a dataframe without indices and you'll discover that `pandas` interprets your matrix row-wise:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(Matrix)
>>> df
     0    1    2
0  [0]  [0]  [0]
1  [0]  [0]  [0]
```

So you need to transpose your data (or swap the `columns` and `index` arguments). This does the job:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(Matrix, index=da, columns=cl).transpose()
>>> df
     A    B
X  [0]  [0]
Y  [0]  [0]
Z  [0]  [0]
```

PS. I wonder if you really want the brackets around each value. But maybe you have a reason...

Comment: I am Facing this issue still may be when i update the matrix array its look like this before making dataframe:
`[[array([ 27.51970205]), array([ 29.99031114]), array([ 37.8568863])], [array([ 6.55124158]), array([ 7.56538462]), array([ 9.875])]]` so may be that use this array may create this problem

Comment: Well anyway that's unrelated to your question, which I trust I have answered.

Comment: its simply, as you transpose the dataframe. which is not working in my case, i just do something else and its working as matrix is a list so i revser the list instead of doing your way and it works. replace `Matrix` with `list(map(list, zip(*Matrix)))`.